# Python Facebook API v3.1

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-python-business-sdk

I am new to facebook API, I was looking through the code given [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-business-sdk/tree/master/examples) with example so I have been calling script for `AdsInsightsEdgeAdCampaignInsights.py` by replacing the credential related variables . But I am getting an error as follows :

```
  Message: Call was not successful
  Method:  GET
  Path:    https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/10153882624547484/insights
  Params:  {'breakdown': 'publisher_platform', 'fields': 'impressions'}

  Status:  400
  Response:
    {
      "error": {
        "message": "Unsupported operation", 
        "code": 100, 
        "type": "OAuthException", 
        "fbtrace_id": "A/HinNJOAqs"
      }
    }
```

I have following queries:

1. why it is calling `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/10153882624547484/insights` , why version `v2.11`?
2. How should I call using API version `v3.1`?
3. Any Python Facebook API documentation for v3.1

Answer (score 0):

Hej Piyush,

I think it is calling v2.11 instead of v3.1 because in the import statement for `AdsInsightsEdgeAdCampaignInsights.py`, it calls `from facebookads` where as from v3.0 onwards, Facebook merged all the Advertiser & Business APIs and called the module `facebook_business`.

I tested it for myself and after changing it to

```
from facebook_business.adobjects.adsetimport AdSet
from facebook_business.adobjects.adsinsights import AdsInsights
from facebook_business.api import FacebookAdsApi
```

it worked for me.

When it comes to the documentation of their own API and updating it properly, Facebook is pretty sloppy in my opinion.